# How real world get translated into dreams

Tags: karma, dream

In our dream we keep hearing sounds which are coming from outside environment , those sounds seamlessly blend into dream.

Ex: if the alarm goes off, in dreams it blends and we dog barking continuously. Some kind of dangers also peek in and warn us - like getting hit by car, drowning etc

- How is possible?
- Do dreams travel in waves?
- Are warnings based on Karma?

  - Some of our fore fathers are warning?

Comment: Sir, I want know what Vedas say. I want to stress on Karma part.

Comment: OK, then edit your question to focus on the Karma part, and make it clear that you want to know what the Vedas say on the matter.

Comment: What do you mean by "outside" while you are dreaming?

Comment: Outside means our surroundings, like alarm sound, someone knocking door. These get translated into dreams. I experienced many times.

Comment: @user76466 As I said, if you want your question reopened then you should focus it one thing, rather ham just asking a generic dream question which would just be a duplicate of a previous question.  Like if you're specifically interested on whether the Vedas talk about dreams being related to Karma, as you said before, then edit your question to focus on that.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Upanishads, there are 4 states of consciousness. The waking, dream, dreamless, and the Turiya.The first 3 states are what are experienced by us as living beings, the 4th state (Turiya) is the consciousness of Brahman (Mandukyopanishad 1-7).

Mandukya Upanishad (II.1) - "The wise declare the falsity of all objects in a dream because of the location of the objects inside (the body) and because of (their) contraction."